# Gem repository not found when installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems, installation

I have Ruby 1.8.7 and Ruby 1.9.2 installed on my Windows Machine.

In my console when I do `ruby -v` it gives me Ruby 1.8.7

Now when I try

```
gem install rails -v 2.3.8
```

I get this error

```
ERROR:  http://gems.rubyforge.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  could not find gem rails locally or in a repository
```

My RubyGems version show 1.3.5 so I tried to update it

```
gem update --system
```

I get this error

```
Updating RubyGems
ERROR:  http://gems.rubyforge.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
Errno::E10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by
its access permissions. - connect(2) (http://gems.rubyforge.org/yaml)`
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Sorry Guys I voted to close this question. Actually I made a silly mistake, my AV's firewall was on which I didn't take care of. And got into this. Sorry

Answer (score 11):

Give this a try.

```
gem sources
```

That will show you what sources you are using.

```
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org
gem sources -a http://gems.github.com
gem sources -a http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

Those will add the most used gem sources.

Comment: Should be using rubygems.org as the official source now.

Comment: If you get the error: http://gems.rubyonrails.org does not appear to be a repository remove that repo from your sources list.

`gem sources -r http://gems.rubyonrails.org`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, but when I tried to set the company's proxy with SET HTTP_PROXY, I got a problem because the proxy uses NTLM validation and I needed to specify my AD-Domin which won't work wit gem. The way I got around it was installing fiddler and starting it and then setting

`SET HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:8888`

afterwards my gems installed like a charm!