# How do I install CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rubygems, cocoapods

I referred to many links and tried, but I had no success. I read CocoaPods documents and many times tried to install, but I always failed because of the starting steps. I found one error whereby I can't install gems first. What are the steps one by one? Such as steps or a demo of how to install.

[This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/156971/cocoapods-tutorial-swift-getting-started) is one link which I tried.

The screenshot refers to this console error I was given:

[image]

Comment: This is probably related to ruby version, Check version of ruby, ruby -v, what does it says ?

Comment: I think this is the answer for your question check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238340/how-can-i-get-past-http-gems-rubyforge-org-does-not-appear-to-be-a-repositor

Answer (score 907):

#### POD Install

1. Open terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo gem install cocoapods
   ```

   The Gem will get installed in Ruby inside the System library. Or try on [Mac OS X v10.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) (El Capitan), type:

   ```
   sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
   ```

   If there is an error "activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.xx", then install latest activesupport first by typing in the terminal.

   ```
   sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6
   ```
2. After installation, there will be a lot of messages. Read them and if no error found, it means the CocoaPods installation is done. Next, you need to setup the CocoaPods master repository. Type in the terminal:

   ```
   pod setup
   ```

   And wait it will download the master repository. The size is very big (370.0 MB in December 2016). So it can be a while. You can track of the download by opening *Activity* and go to the *Network* tab and search for "git-remote-https". Alternatively, you can try adding "--verbose" to the command like so:

   ```
   pod setup --verbose
   ```
3. Once done, it will output "Setup Complete", and you can create your Xcode project and save it.
4. Then in the terminal, *[cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command))* to your Xcode project root directory (where your `.xcodeproj` file resides) and type:

   ```
   pod init
   ```
5. Then open your project's podfile by typing in terminal:

   ```
   open -a Xcode Podfile
   ```
6. Your Podfile will get open in text mode. Initially there will be some default commands in there. Here is where you add your project's dependencies. For example, in the podfile, type

   ```
   pod 'AFNetworking', '0.9.1'
   ```

   (This line is an example of adding the AFNetworking library to your project.)

   Other tips:

   Uncomment  `platform :ios, '9.0'` 
   Uncomment  `use_frameworks!` if you're using Swift

   When you are done editing the podfile, save it and close Xcode.
7. Then install pods into your project by typing in terminal:

   ```
   pod install
   ```

   or (For m1 chip)

   ```
   arch -x86_64 pod install
   ```

   Depending how many libraries you added to your podfile for your project, the time to complete this varies. Once completed, there will be a message that says

   > "Pod installation complete! There are X dependencies from the Podfile
   > and X total pods installed."

   Now close your Xcode project. Then *locate* and open the `.xcworkspace` Xcode project file and start coding. (You should no longer open the `xcodeproj` file.)

Comment: 'pod install' takes forever. I checked in Activity Monitor > Network tab
git-remote-https : Rcvd Packets are very slow, though I have good internet.

Comment: Don't use sudo to install gems.  That's a bad habit to be in.

Comment: `sudo gem install cocoapods` returns `ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
 cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method 'invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: WORTH NOTING you may have to install ruby-2.0.0-p481 I'm using rvm and simply did rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p481 then rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p481 after that the instructions for el Capitan worked like a charm.

Comment: `pod setup` took about 30 min with 15mb internet speed :|

Comment: could not be much simpler

Comment: NEVER EVER install with SUDO. Never do this, you will get in trouble

Answer (score 73):

1. First open your terminal
2. Then update your gem file with command

   ```
   sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
   ```
3. Then give your project path

   ```
   cd /your project path
   ```
4. Touch the podifle

   ```
   touch podfile
   ```
5. Open your podfile

   ```
   open -e podfile
   ```
6. It will open a podfile like a text edit. Then set your target. For example if you want to set up Google maps then your podfile should be like

   ```
   use_frameworks!
   target 'yourProjectName' do
       pod 'GoogleMaps'
   end
   ```
7. Then install the pod

   ```
   pod install
   ```

Comment: I got the below error after "pod install" :(

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] Unable to locate the executable `node`.

 #  from /Users/{user}/Documents/GitHub/ActivityList/ios/Podfile:45
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    # react-native-cli autolinking
 >    use_native_modules!
 #  end
 #  -------------------------------------------

Answer (score 67):

On [macOS v10.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) (Mojave) with Xcode 10.3, I got scary warnings from the `gem` route with or without `-n /usr/local/bin`:

```
xcodeproj's executable "xcodeproj" conflicts with /usr/local/bin/xcodeproj
Overwrite the executable? [yN]
```

What works for me is still Homebrew. Just:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Comment: This indeed worked for me. And it was pretty straightforward. I tried the sudo gem install, did not seem to work for me.

Comment: Tried sudo gem install but didn't work. Tried sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods but still no luck. But tried brew install cocoapods and boom everything right on the track.

Comment: How should one deal with this scary warning? I think the warning exists because you already have the homebrew version of cocoapods installed. Homebrew executables are usually located in `usr/local/bin`

Comment: Homebrew worked on `Catilina` as well, like a charm.

Comment: Is it possible to install a specific version of cocoapods with brew? brew install cocoapods@1.11.2 doesn't work :(

Answer (score 48):

**This works for [Mac OS X v10.11.x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) (El Capitan)**

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

After this, you can set up the pod using pod setup cmd and then move to your project directory and install pod.

Comment: @Jayesh For me this was the only one worked... and you saved my day... :)

Comment: @Joker i take 2 day's for solving pod problem.. :)

Comment: First you need follow step of @Om Prakash Answer

Comment: Am I correct in saying that for the first step when you call "pod setup", you can be in any directory and don't have to be in your actual project directory to do the pod setup?

Answer (score 23):

**Simple steps to install a pod file:**

1. Open the terminal
2. Command on the terminal: **sudo gem install cocoapods**
3. Set your project path in the terminal.
4. Command: **pod init**
5. Go to the pod file of your project and add the pod which you want to install
6. Added in the pod file: **pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0**
7. Command: **Pod install**
8. Close the Xcode project
9. open your project from the terminal
10. Command: open PodDemos.xcworkspace

Comment: Why the rollback? It's easier to understand with the correct formatting.

Answer (score 16):

**Year 2020, installing CocoaPods v1.9.1 in [macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina)**

1. First set up your Xcode version in your Mac using the terminal.

   ```
   sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app
   ```
2. Next, install CocoaPods using the terminal.

   ```
   sudo gem install cocoapods
   ```

For more information, visit the official website, https://cocoapods.org/.

Answer (score 15):

These are the complete steps that I usually follow. I am posting these steps as short as possible and assuming that you know about Mac and Xcode projects. First of all, open the terminal and use the following commands, and press enter after each command.

Type in the following command if you don't already have CocoaPods installed:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Now please move to your Xcode Project directory by using this following command, and replace `/Your Xcode Project Directory Path` with the actual path to the directory:

```
cd /Your Xcode Project Directory Path
```

Below are instructions for how to use CocoaPods. Please wait for some time after each and every command entered to the terminal to execute successfully.

1. Searching for pods in terminal:

   `pod search networking` (replace networking with which you want to search)
2. Creating the pod file:

   `pod init`
3. Opening the pod file:

   `open -a Xcode Podfile`
4. Adding the pods: (After adding your pods you must save the podfile first and then head back to the terminal again.)

   ```
   target 'WebServiceUsingMantleAFNetworking' do
   # platform :ios, '8.0' //Choose your version of iOS
   pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6.0’

   end
   ```

   OR

   ```
   platform :ios, '8.0'
   pod 'AFNetworking'
   pod 'Mantle'
   pod 'LBBlurredImage'
   pod 'TSMessages'
   pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
   ```
5. Installing the pods:

   `pod install`
6. Check for updates of pods on existing project:

   `pod outdated`
7. Update the existing pods:

   `pod update`
8. Uninstall the Cocoapods from system:

   `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

   There is a complete tutorial for removing pods from your Xcode project on Stack Overflow. You can check on this following link for more info.

   *[How to remove CocoaPods from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project/32921657#32921657)*

Answer (score 11):

Here are *all* steps with an image. Please follow it properly and I am sure you will not get any error.

From *[How to install CocoaPods and setup with your Xcode project](http://blogs.triffort.com/?p=309)*.

---

First of all, check you have to install `command line` or not.

> You can check this by opening Xcode, navigating the menu to
>
> Xcode → *Preferences* → *Downloads* → *Components*. Find *Command Line Tools* and select install/update.
>
> [image: Commandline tool]

If you haven't found `command line tool` then you need to write this command in the terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

And click on install.

If you have installed the command-line tool, you need to select your Xcode directory (sometimes these type of problems created due to different versions of Xcode available)

Follow this procedure.

> Open terminal and run this command:
>
> ```
> sudo gem install cocoapods
> ```
>
> Enter the admin password. This could take a while. After a few minutes, it
> will show a green message if CocoaPods installed successfully in your
> Mac machine.
>
> If you are getting any error with Xcode 6 like developer path is
> missing. First run this command in terminal:
>
> `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode6.app (or your XCodeName.app)`
>
> Now you can set up Pod with your Xcode project.

And now you have to install pod. Follow this procedure.

> 1. Open Terminal
> 2. Change directory to your Xcode project root directory (where your
>    ProjectName.xcodeproj file is placed).
> 3. `pod setup`: (Setting up the CocoaPods master repository)
>
> If successful, it shows: **Setup completed** (read-only access). So,
> you set up everything. Now let’s do something which is more visible…Yes! Let’s install libraries in your Xcode project.

Now you have to set up and update the library related to pod in your project.

> **Steps to add-remove-update libraries in pod:**
>
> 1. Open Terminal
> 2. Change directory to your Xcode project root directory. If your
>    terminal is already running then there isn't any need to do this, as you are
>    already at the same path.
> 3. `touch pod file`
> 4. `open -e podfile` (This should open a blank text file)
> 5. Add your library names in that text file. You can add new names
>    (library name), remove any name or change the version, e.g.:
>
>    ```
>    pod ’Facebook-iOS-SDK’
>    pod ’EGOTableViewPullRefresh’
>    pod ’JSONKit’
>    pod ‘MBProgressHUD
>    ```
>
> **NOTE:** Use the (<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>”</kbd>) button to add single quote at both end of library name. It should be shown as straight vertical line. Without
> control button it shall be added as curly single quote which will give
> error while installation of file.
>
> 6. Save and close this text file. Now libraries are set up and you have
>    to install/update it
> 7. Go to your terminal again and run this command: `pod install`
>    (to install/update these libraries in pod).
>
> You should see output similar to the following:
>
> ```
> Updating spec repo `master’ \
> Installing Facebook-iOS-SDK \
> Generating support files
> ```

Setup completed.

**Note:**

If you have followed this whole procedure correctly and step by step, then you can directly fire the `pod update` command after selecting `Xcode` and then select your project path. And write your command `pod update`.

You can also check a command line tool here:

[image: Command line tool in Location]

Comment: When you quote someone else's work, please use quote formatting to indicate what has been copied (it is a little dishonest not to). Additionally, it is more honest to state up-front the source link where the copied text comes from, instead of at the bottom of your answer.

Answer (score 11):

1. Open Terminal
2. Type in `sudo gem install cocoapods` if you don't have CocoaPods
3. Enter `cd /project path`, but replace `project path` with actual project path
4. touch podfile
5. Use one of the following commands to open the podfile:
   `open -e podfile` to open in TextEdit or
   `open -a pod file` to open in Xcode
6. Set your target and add pod file of GoogleMaps like as:

   ```
   target 'PROJECT NAME HERE' do
   pod 'GoogleMaps'
   end
   ```
7. Use `pod install` to install dependencies

Comment: thanks for sharing!
Didn't know I can open a document inside a seperate window or in xCode through the bash! :)

Answer (score 9):

**CocoaPods Installation on [macOS v10.13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra) (High Sierra):**

1. Install Homebrew - https://brew.sh/
2. Execute the following commands in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo gem update --system
   sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6

   sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

   pod setup

   pod setup --verbose
   ```

Answer (score 9):

For [macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina):

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.8.4
```

The latest CocoaPods 1.10.0 seem not to be working.

I found the answer in *[Trouble with installing CocoaPods](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668456)*.

Answer (score 9):

On mac M1
I had two cocoapods installed, one was using brew and one with gem. With 2 different versions.
After reading many of your posts, and try many things I encountered various troubles.

Finally this one help me : thanks to [Evan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17845399/evan)

With his post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70600723/2355088

The final working sequence for me probably was :

- sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
- brew uninstall cocoapods
- brew install cocoapods
- brew reinstall ruby
- => **RESTART ALL TERMS** <= magical step, thank you Evan
- cd myProj
- pod install

Comment: Thanks! These steps helped me clean up my environment. I looks like I had it installed via both `gem` and `brew`.

Answer (score 8):

1- Install the Cocoapods in your machine

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods

$ pod setup --verbose
```

2- Check whether Cocoapods is installed on your machine or not?

> `$ pod --version`

3- Go to your project directory where .xcodeproj is present

```
$ pod init
```

- After using `pod init` one additional file is added in your folder of name Podfile.

4- By double click open the podfile and pods between `target` and `end`

5- Install Pod using command

```
pod install
```

- When you run the pod install command it installs all pods which you write in the pod file. And after you install the required commands open the project directory you get 2 new files.

> First is Podfile.lock -> Every time the pod install command is run — and downloads and install new pods — it writes the version it has installed, for each pod, in the Podfile.lock file.

> Second is .xcworkspace -> Xcode workspace files can be used as a wrapper or container for an Xcode .XCODEPROJ project.

**Now use your library by using .xcworkspace which have a white background colour.**

Answer (score 7):

Pod installation giving an error on *[Mac OS X v10.11.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) (El Capitan)*:

> **ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods: 
>
> activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.**

[image]

After getting this error, I tried this command and installed again. It worked for me.

```
sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6
```

Now try the same pod installation command

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Answer (score 6):

For me, the easiest way was to install via a Ruby gem:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v
```

Please note `-v` for verbose. It takes a while to install CocoaPods and often you get confused if it's really happening.

Answer (score 6):

You can install CocoaPods via Homebrew in macOS.

First, open your terminal, and run this code (for installing Homebrew if you have not): Go [here](https://brew.sh/#:%7E:text=/bin/bash%20-c%20%22%24(curl%20-fsSL%20https%3A//raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)%22) for the latest command.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Then install CocoaPods easily via this command:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

This worked for me. `-n` helps you fix the permission error.

Answer (score 5):

Pod File Install Steps

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Pod setup

```
cd ~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/ShowTracker

touch podfile
open -a Xcode Podfile // To open it in Xcode
OPEN -e podfile       // To open it in text editor
pod install           // To install a new pod
pod update            // To update all pods
```

Answer (score 5):

Works in macOS Big Sur

1 install LATEST version of brew (https://treehouse.github.io/installation-guides/mac/homebrew)

2 then use "brew uninstall cocoapods"

3 install the latest version of cocoapods using "brew install cocoapods" (You must verify installed version with github version https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.11.2, they must match)

4 overwrite link to cocoapods with "brew link --overwrite cocoapods"

5 check the version of cocoapods "pod --version"

6 done, You have the latest version of cocoapods installed

Answer (score 4):

If you behind a proxy then pass the proxy as an argument:

```
sudo gem install --http-proxy http://user:password@www-proxy.example.com:80 cocoapods
```

Answer (score 4):

Normally we use

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Solution, fix for CocoaPods error on [Mac OS X v10.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) (El Capitan):

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
pod setup
cd /project path
pod init
```

In Podfile we need to set the target

```
# Podfile

platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!

# My other pods

target “Projectname” do

    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'
    pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.1.1'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.2'
    pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding', '~> 1.2'

end

target 'ProjectnameTests' do
    testing_pods
end

target 'ProjectnameUITests' do
    testing_pods
end
```

In the console - terminal

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 3):

**CocoaPods installation step:**

Open your Terminal:

```
sudo gem update --system

sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6

sudo gem install cocoapods

pod setup

pod setup --verbose
```

Then go to your project directory with Terminal:

```
cd Your Project Path
```

Then enter the below command in Terminal:

```
pod init

open -a Xcode Podfile
```

*(Edit POD file with pod ‘libname’)*

```
pod install
```

Comment: Missing steps for El Capitan OS: sudo gem install cocoapods (which will throw errors by default)

neonichu @ GitHub: This is the solution when you are receiving the "Operation not permitted" error.

$ mkdir -p $HOME/Software/ruby
$ export GEM_HOME=$HOME/Software/ruby
$ gem install cocoapods
[...]
1 gem installed
$ export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Software/ruby/bin
$ pod --version
0.37.2

For details - https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3692

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [SwiftBoy's 10-step solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56375815/2348597) I successfully used CocoaPods to setup the latest version of [*AudioKit*](https://audiokit.io/downloads/).

**1.** Using Xcode create **MyAudioApp** Swift project saving it to my Developer directory e.g.

```
    /Users/me/Developer/MyAudioApp
```

**2.** Using Cocoapods install AudioKit within MyAudioApp project (i.e. install AudioKit sdk)

**3.** Open Terminal, type command below and press *Enter*

```
    sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

**4.** Provide system password and press *Enter*

**5.** In Terminal, type command below and press *Enter*

```
    cd /Users/me/Developer/MyAudioApp
```

**6.** Create project pod file - in Terminal type command below and press *Enter*

```
    touch Podfile
```

**7.** Open project pod file - in Terminal type command below and press *Enter* (opens in TextEdit)

```
    open Podfile
```

**8.** Edit code below into open pod file (and save file before quitting TextEdit)

```
    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
        platform :ios, '12.2'
        use_frameworks!

        target 'MyAudioApp' do
        pod 'AudioKit', '~> 4.7'
    end
```

**9.** To install AudioKit in MyAudioApp workspace type Terminal command below and press Enter

```
    Pod install
```

and wait for install to finish

**10.** In Finder, go to project folder **/Users/me/Developer/MyAudioApp**
    and click **.xcworkspace** file below (opens in Xcode!)

```
    /Users/me/Developer/MyAudioApp/MyAudioApp.xcworkspace
```

**11.** In MyAudioApp edit ViewController.swift and insert the following

```
    import AudioKit
```

Answer (score 2):

For CocoaPods in the terminal, follow this:

```
sudo gem update

sudo gem install cocoapods

pod setup

cd (project direct drag link)

pod init

open -aXcode podfile # (If it’s already open, add your pod file name. Example: alamofire4.3)

pod install

pod update
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open *Terminal*
2. Enter *$ sudo gem install cocoapods* command in terminal
3. Create new Xcode project
4. Navigate to directory containing Xcode project. Use *cd “../directory-location/..”* or *cd [drag-and-drop project folder]*
5. *Pod install*

[image: Screenshot for steps]

If this prompts error *`Unable to add a source with url..`* then install command line tool for Xcode. Again, rerun Pod install command.

This will install all dependencies as well.

Now, open your *project in Workspace* i.e. Project-Name.xcworkspace rather than Project-Name.xcodeproj

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **install CocoaPods for the first time** for your project.

Example: Here we will install the "Alamofire" SDK using CocoaPods step by step.

**Step 1.** Open Terminal, hit command, and then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

**Step 2.** If it asks, you should **provide system password** and then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

**Step 3.** With **command “cd” and give the path of your project** and then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

*Note: type the "cd" command then space and drag the project folder to the terminal. It will take the project path as shown below (here my project name is: Simple Alamofire)*

```
cd  /Users/ramdhanchoudhary/Documents/Swift\ Workspace/Simple\
Alamofire
```

[image]

**Step 4.** Create a pod file in your project by terminal by command “touch Podfile” and press “Enter”

```
touch Podfile
```

**Step 5.** Then, open “Podfile” by terminal command “open Podfile” and press “Enter”

```
open Podfile
```

**Step 6.** Now type following code in opened pod file then save and close file

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    platform :ios, '10.0'
    use_frameworks!

    target '<Your Target Name>' do
            pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
    end
```

**Step 7.** Back in Terminal type command “Pod install” and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> Key.

```
Pod install
```

**Step 8.** Wait for the install to get complete 100% its around 650+ MB

Step 9. That's it goto project folder and open below file

```
<your project name>.xcworkspace
```

Step 10. Import Alamofire class and use!!

```
import Alamofire
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
gem install -p http://proxy_ip:proxy_port compass
```

You might need to add your user name and password to it:

```
gem install -p http://[username]:[password]@proxy_ip:proxy_port compass
```

And check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825178/problem-with-installing-gems-rails) it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

#### For [Mac OS X v10.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) (El Capitan)

`rvm install ruby-2.2.2.`

`rvm use ruby-2.2.2.`

`sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem in mac after updating to macOS 12.1
Also you might get error attached with Ruby framework installed on your mac machine.

- `You just need to remove cocoa pods completely from mac and re-install cocoapods`
- `And then reinstall your project pods`

This will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

for Apple Silicon Mac

```
$ sudo gem uninstall ffi && sudo gem install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc
```