# How to create a CocoaPod with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, xcode7

I create a swift cocoa touch `framework` according to [create cocoapod with siwft](http://basememara.com/how-to-create-a-cocoapod-with-swift/)

and it works fine, But there is another problem, my framework will dependency on other `framework`, such as `SwiftyJSON`.

And I try add

```
s.dependency "SwiftyJSON", "~> 2.3"
```

into the `.podspec file`.
But when I try to build my 'Example', still error happens :

> 'No such module SwiftyJSON'

Comment: Check the readme of `SwiftyJSON` to find out how to integrate it via CocoaPods: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#user-content-cocoapods-ios-8-os-x-109

Comment: @Cristik thanks, I know how to do.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and goto to your folder project. Then follow this step. Type this command in your terminal.

```
open -a TextEdit Podfile
```

Then copy this `pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git =>'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'`

put into Podfile. Then save it. And type this command in your terminal.

```
pod install
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

First you should install cocoapods package  in your mac 
check this tutorial to do this [How to install cocoapods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-to-install-cocoapods)

Then you can install any cocoapods for any project by the following steps

- open  terminal
- navigate to the root path for the project, example

  ```
  cd /Users/mac/Desktop/cocoatest
  ```
- then type

  ```
  pod init
  ```

  (the will generate file "Podfile" ) open it
  the content for this file will be something like this:

  ```
  # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
  # platform :ios, '9.0'

  target 'cocotest' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for cocotest

  end




  uncomment this line # platform :ios, '9.0' 

  and then add you cocoapods under this line 
  # Pods for cocotest
  ```

like

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'cocotest' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for cocotest


pod "SwiftyJSON", "~> 2.3"
end
```

then save the file

- after that type `pod install` in terminal and it will create file with 
  xcworkspace extension open it and that is your project