# Using OpenSSL cocoa pod in iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, openssl, cocoapods

I'm trying to import OpenSSL pod header files into my iOS project. However, Xcode cannot find `OpenSSL` header. It says

```
#import <OpenSSL/bio.h>
```

`OpenSSL/bio.h` file not found

But I was able to `command + click` to jump to the `bio.h`

The OpenSSL pod is installed successfully and my `PodFile` is like below

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do
pod 'OpenSSL', '~> 1.0'
end
```

using Xcode 7.2

#### Edit

I have tried clean, build and delete `Derived Data` folder but still not working.

Comment: be sure you open right file (xcworkspace)

Comment: I could be wrong since I don't use Swift or Ciciapods, but C is case-sensitive. That usually means you ***`#import <openssl/bio.h>`***, and not ***`#import <OpenSSL/bio.h>`***. Also, If your OpenSSL is installed locally, you usually use ***`#import "openssl/bio.h"`***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) I have created sample project
2) Added `pod 'OpenSSL', '~> 1.0'`
3) Closed project and then opened Project_Name.xcworkspace
4) used `#import <OpenSSL/bio.h>`
5) `Command + Shift + K` (for cleaning project)
6) `Command + Shift + B` (for building it)

It worked for me on `Xcode7.2`. Try this.

Comment: Can you please help me to add openssl in my project step by step.

Comment: @Ravi do you want to add `OpenSSL` pod in your project?

Comment: yes, i have tried, using terminal written "pod init", next what should i do. One more thing, only pod file is sufficient for OpenSSL library. Please explain me clearly.

Comment: @Ravi please follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-to-install-cocoa-pods
 for setting up pods in iOS project, and yes you only need pods for openssl library.

Answer (score 0):

Build the project after you add a pod dependency to the project.

`Command + b` will do the job.