# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to run this project [MZFormSheetController](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController) But I get this error

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

I have imported JGMethodSwizzler too in the project which I downloaded from here

https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGMethodSwizzler

but still it gives this error. I am really stuck here
I cleaned the project and also deleted the FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS also but still nothing is working

Comment: use cocoapod it is good for dependency.http://stackoverflow.com/a/32642692/4910767

Comment: I have had the same problem before. I solved my [disabling bitcode](https://medium.com/@president/how-to-disable-bitcode-or-enable-bitcode-in-xcode-7-5d59b13d9230). I'm not sure if it applies to you, but it may help.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to drag and drop `JGMethodSwizzler` folder in your project and write `#import "JGMethodSwizzler.h"` in the `viewcontroller` you need, it works fine for me.

Comment: well I don't know which controller needs this library since I am running this library directly without doing any changings and which turns out giving me problems