# Project size increased by 500 mb after installing pods

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

After I have installed cocoa pods in my project, the project size has increased from 200 kb to 515 mb. Any suggestions to find the mistake and reduce the size is most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which pods you installed ? any specification ?

Comment: I think it's normal to have size increased, but that doesn't means that the compiled size of the app will increase. I think your preoccupation must be the download size of your app that your users will download

Comment: @AshishThakkar It's cocoa pods. Have added in the question.

Comment: pls show ur podfile.

Comment: you will find actual size of app when you create the ipa file.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Thank You! After your response, while checking I came across the specs folder inside my project which contains hell lot of frameworks, I guess. That is taking the whole size. Not sure if I can attach the screen shot, or how shall I show you the pod file? Any suggestions for next step?

Comment: @AshishThakkar Thank you, but I'm also concerned about the project size. So, trying to find out if anything has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I had pulled the whole master repo in my project location, which resulted in the specs folder containing the whole frameworks with all the versions. And, that was something occupying so much of space.

To resolve the same, I removed the pod from my project completely with the reference of the answer mentioned here :

[How to remove CocoaPods from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project)

Then, I set up the pods again into my project with the following reference :

[How to install cocoa pods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-to-install-cocoa-pods)

And now everything looks fine and as expected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 'hell of a lot of frameworks' - are they all necessary? The pods in your podfile add to the size of your project. Remove unecessary pods from the podfile, call `pod install` and your project size should decrease.