# How to manually import third party Swift framework into Swift iOS project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, oauth

I am trying to import and use the OAuthSwift library in the Swift iOS project. I followed their directions:

- Drag OAuthSwift.xcodeproj to your project in the Project Navigator.
- Select your project and then your app target. Open the Build Phases panel.
- Expand the Target Dependencies group, and add OAuthSwift framework.
  import OAuthSwift whenever you want to use OAuthSwift.

After completing these steps, importing OAuthSwift using `import OAuthSwift` causes the error `No such module 'OAuthSwift'` and the project fails to build.

I have tried the following steps, based on a number of other SO questions about similar issues:

- Clean and rebuild
- Add the OAuthSwift framework to many different combinations of `Build Phases > Target Dependencies`, `Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries`, `Build Phases > Embed Frameworks`, and `General > Embedded Libraries`
- Set `Build Settings > Search Paths > Framework Search Paths` and `Build Settings > Search Paths > Library Search Paths` to `$(SRCROOT)` and recursive.
- Verify that my deployment target matches the deployment target of the `OAuthSwift` Xcode project.

I have tested this using the latest version of `OAuthSwift` from their master branch using a git submodule, as well as manually downloading and importing each of the two latest tagged versions (0.6.0 and 0.5.2).

I have also created a brand new Xcode project, imported OAuthSwift as above, and encountered the same error.

Finally, I also tried importing a different Swift Framework (Alamofire), following the steps as stated on the README at https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire. This caused the same error as well: `No such module 'Alamofire'`.

I am using:

- OSX 10.11.6
- Xcode 7.3.1
- Swift 2.2

I'm still fairly new to Xcode and the Swift module system, so any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Try: build the project, close Xcode, reopen Xcode, import

Comment: if you are new, adding frameworks can be a bit hard some times, you can add it using cocoapods,, they have it (pod 'OAuthSwift', '~> 0.5.0')

Comment: If they have cocoapods as @Aziz says then I would highly recommend going that route. If your not familiar with it then I suggest you do as almost any popular or good/maintained open source libraries for iOS will use it. Once set up it is super easy to put in/remove 3rd party libraries. As easy as changing one line in a `podfile` and then running `pod install` in command line. Highly recommend it.

Comment: [Link for Installing](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html) // 
[Creating podfile with your desired frameworks](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html)
Then run $ pod install in your projects directory. Clean and build project. May need to restart xcode but its pretty straightforward and can find a lot of examples on cocoapods website.

Comment: USE COCOAPODS! It is awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your life will be a lot easier if you import the framework using CocoaPods. If you haven't used them before, it's really easy once you get set-up. You use Ruby Gems on the command line to install CocoaPods (**sudo gem install cocoapods**) and then create a create a pod file using **pod init**. After this you modify it to include:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

pod 'OAuthSwift', '~> 0.5.0'
```

Save the file and run pod install.

Once this is complete you will have to close out the Xcode project and use the newly created **.xcworkspace project file** (not the .xcodeproj) from here forward.

Here is a link to another post for a secondary reference.
[How to install cocoapods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-to-install-cocoapods)