# Google Sign In Integration iOS 9

Tags: ios, google-signin, ios9.1

I am trying to integrate Google sign-in in my application, but i am getting some errors.

Please help me.

```
Google_SignIn[1409:32870] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b8420b0'
```

and I was added supporting Frameworks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any GoogleSignIn code in your App? And get a clean run without it even with the imported Frameworks?

If not:

Try using Cocoapods instead of just adding the frameworks to your project. This will add all the requirements to your project and it is a cleaner version for adding frameworks. Here you can find a Guide on how to use Cocoapods:

[How to install cocoa pods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-to-install-cocoa-pods) or [Official Cocoapods Getting Started](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html)

And here you can find the actual 'pod' for GoogleSignIn.

[GoogleSignIn Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleSignIn)

Just replace `pod 'AFNetworking', '0.9.1'` for `pod 'GoogleSignIn'` in the linked answer. Remember to open de Xcode Workspace instead of the Xcode Project once you install Cocoapods in your project!