# Facebook Login SDK error on Swift3 on iOS 10

Tags: swift3, facebook-login, xcode8, ios10

The FB Login works fine in the simulator. But when I install the app on a real phone, running iOS 10, it fails with the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit
Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0C77D9D-2B06-485E-B069-55A7026E4336/AZMeal.app/AZMeal
Reason: image not found
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6
```

[image]

There is very little help available on this error, but from what I have read so far, I have tried everything, which includes:

1. copy the SDK in my project
2. switch Link Binary... to Optional
3. insert the FB Login Framework in the Copy Files

However, nothing of it worked. It still gives the same error when it tries to run the app on the phone.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was resolved once I used CocoaPods for Facebook integration.

This blog helped me, which should be top of the Google results, but it is hidden deep down:

http://blog.robkerr.com/facebook-integration-with-swift/

I had to install CocoaPods which was also giving trouble and took a while. The answer which helped me installing it was:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25257238/1198077

Installation of CocoaPods was timing out again and again, though my Internet connection was fine. And every time it would take about 5 minutes before it would time out, until 5th time when it finally went through.