# Xcode doesn't let me import cocoapod module

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using cocoapod, I pretty much followed this answer: [How to install cocoa pods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-to-install-cocoa-pods)
everything went smoothly but after adding the pods to the project Xcode doesn't let me import them.

The pods I think are correctly installed as you can see from the image of the terminal:

[image: pod installed]

but then more often than not I can't import most of them because it's like they can't be read by Xcode:

[image: Like it doesn't even exist]

What can I do?

Comment: your project is on swift and the pod is on ObjectiveC... are you adding the library signature on you project bridging header?

Comment: You do have to build the Pods project successfully for Xcode to recognize the pod framework name. If you comment out the import from this file and then build the whole workspace, do you get any compile errors?

Comment: Also, AFNetworking 0.9.1 is REALLY old, I would investigate how much work it would be to upgrade that or switch to using `NSURLSession` directly.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `UIView+draggable` instead of `UIView_draggable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it in the end: the error was just a bug, I just needed to press cmd+B to make XCode rebuild the project and the error went away.