# Mixing Swift and ObjC pods doesn't work

Tags: ios, cocoapods, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have a podfile with only Objective-C pods, that looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target "myProject" do
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'GooglePlaces'
    pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'RMMapper'
    pod 'Parse'
    pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK'
    pod 'PocketSVG', '~> 0.7'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Answers'
    pod 'lottie-ios'
end
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

and a bridiging header that looks like this:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import "PocketSVG.h"
#import <Lottie/Lottie.h>
```

Now, I want to add Alamofire, which is a Swift pod. So I have to use `use_frameworks!`, and my podfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target "myProject" do
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'GooglePlaces'
    pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'RMMapper'
    pod 'Parse'
    pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK'
    pod 'PocketSVG', '~> 0.7'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Answers'
    pod 'lottie-ios'
    pod 'Alamofire'    # Added
    use_frameworks!    # Added
end
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

but when I'm trying to build my project, I get 2 errors:

The first is on my bridging header:

> 'PocketSVG.h' file not found

The second is not on a specific file:

> Failed to import bridging header

Any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`use_framework` will make the libs specified in the pod file linked as dynamic libraries. You should use `#import <PocketSVG/PocketSVG.h>` or `@import PocketSVG;`

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

1. open podfile with command -> open podfile

and put the below text in that podfile

```
target 'Myproject' do
 platform :ios, '10.0'
 use_frameworks!
 pod 'GoogleMaps'
 pod 'GooglePlaces'
 pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
 pod 'GoogleMaps'
 pod 'RMMapper'
 pod 'Parse'
 pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK'
 pod 'PocketSVG', '~> 0.7'
 pod 'Fabric'
 pod 'Answers'
 pod 'lottie-ios'
 pod 'Alamofire' 
end
```

No need to add extra lines 
after that just type command pod install 
I hope it will work!

Comment: @FS.O6 do you installed cocoapod?

Comment: Of course, and everything works fine when I delete the `pod "Alamofire"' and the 'use_frameworks!`

Comment: @FS.O6 Please refer this one i hope you can get an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-to-install-cocoa-pods

Comment: @FS.O6 just go through once the steps then you can understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142280/discussion-between-bhupat-bheda-and-fs-o6).