# Xcode-7, Could not build Module <IBMMobileFirstFoundation>

Tags: xcode, macos, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am facing an issue, related to cordova ios build using Xcode-7.
when I create fresh project on mac machine, I am able to build and run that on simulator ios 6s. But When I try to import the project built on windows machine to mac, I am not able to build it succesfully.

***Error:*

> could not build module "IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation".

**

*Configuration on windows:

cordova 6.5.0

ionic 3.3.0

node 6.10.3

ios platform version is 4.4.0

npm version is 3.10.10

*
*configuration on mac machine

cordova 6.5.0

ionic 3.3.0

node 6.11

ios platform version is 4.4.0

npm version is 3.10.10

*

Xcode is 7.

thank you for kind attention, kindly suggest me what I doing wrong.
:)

Comment: Did you run a pod install before running it on mac?

Comment: Nope, can you please tell me bit about that ?

Comment: Navigate to the root folder of your ios project and run the command "pod install". Prior to it, you should have cocoa pods installed.
Also have you checked if the MFP plugin has been added to the project properly?

Comment: mfp plugin is installed, but i didnt understand why should I use pod install? why it is required ?

Comment: It resolves the dependencies.

Comment: I try to run "pod install", but it says pod is not a command

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-to-install-cocoa-pods . Please install cocoapods as mentioned here and try to do a `pod install`.

Comment: *thank you very much, i try to install the pod*, there is no podfile in my project Keerhti

Comment: When do you see the error ? Can you upload your project to a file sharing service & provide the link

Comment: Yeah sue,i can share the complete stack trace with you.

Comment: I just came to know, issue is with the cordova-mfp-plugin.
|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one week R&D, I found the the answer to the problem, there was the problem of Xcode version, I just updated the OS version and also the Xcode version. Later On I came to know that problem was cordova and ionic version also. I update the cordova version to 7.2.0 and ionic version to 3.4.0.

I have build the app and its running fine, with some UI issues.

also use ionic cordova build to build the project.
 thank you.