# Running pod init for Xcode - when should I see Podfile?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

After I run `pod init` in the terminal to add a Podfile to an Xcode project, I thought I would see it added to my Xcode project - instead it is seems to be only added to the folder for the Xcode project in the file system, and I have to add it manually into the Xcode project and then run `pod install`. From there on, I can see it in my `xcworkspace`.

My question is - is this the correct way to add a podfile? Should I not see it in my Xcode project immediately after running `pod init` in the terminal? Do I have to manually drag it into the Xcode project and then run `pod install`?

Comment: [This stackoverflow answer one of best pod init answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25257238/3589771).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Podfile will be automatically added to your Xcode project after you run `pod install`; you don't have to drag it in manually.

Answer (score 2):

When you add the pod file and run `pod init` you won't see changes in your **project** because the changes are made to the **workspace**.

So after installing and running `pod init` you need to open the .xcworkspace file instead of the .xcproj file. In fact, I think there is a message in the terminal that tells you what file you should open.