# Cocoa pod issues

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, cocoapods

I'm trying to add a pod from [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org) website. I haven't used pods before this, so I'm a bit of a nascence with it. I've added the cocoapods program in the terminal and via their client software from the cocoapods website. When trying to add the pod from the terminal I got into a loop in the Podfile file. When using the client software I got a messaging saying successfully installed, but it ends u not actually adding on my project. I'm just trying to add the "[SwiftyGif pod](https://cocoapods.org/?q=swiftyGif)" to my gif making app. I've followed step-by-step of the installation on the Cocoapods website. I just can't get it to work after trying for the last week. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some details about what commands you used and what did the terminal show you?

Comment: Read the how to at least 10 times. Maybe you will figure out.

Comment: @DominikBucher Honestly I did. I've followed the steps and kept getting myself into a loop when editing the pod file. Every time I saved the pod file it made me rewrite it..

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-to-install-cocoapods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run

```
pod init
```

in the directory of your app, which will allow you to install it. Save the pod file, and then run

```
pod install
```

on the directory and open the workspace file, not the project file. Your pods should be their, underneath your app in the Xcode file explorer.
Hope this works!

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. How do I tell it how to install the SwiftyGif pod then? Do I just run "pod 'SwiftyGif', '~> 3.1'" after "pod init" and before "pod install"?