# I can't install firebase pod with terminal

Tags: ios, firebase, terminal, installation, cocoapods

There is a red error in my terminal when I am installing Firebase/Core in my project. I can install other pods such as SwiftyJSON, but I can't do it with Firebase! Can anyone help me?!

```
[!] Error installing Firebase
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/g5/fqsn7z4d25s2kc7ycblfgnn40000gn/T/d20180516-4404-1t05mp4/file.tgz https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/c84ce83f9f8217ed/Firebase-5.0.1.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
```

Comment: Hope this helps.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-to-install-cocoapods

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't! I can install other pods, such as SwiftyJSON or ... But for Firebase, I always see this error!

Comment: can you post your init Firebase line in `Podfile`

Comment: @Mr.7th Please check you firebase pod setup. It should be like this https://cocoapods.org/pods/Firebase

Comment: @QuocNguyen
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
  platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Flash Chat' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Flash Chat
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'

end

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya I did it, but I still I can't get the result.

Comment: @Mr.7th : I tried with your Podfile, but nothing wrong

Comment: @QuocNguyen I guess, I got what is the main problem. Maybe it is related to my networking. I will get connected to a good and safe VPN and try again. I will inform you ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Your podfile should look like following

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target ‘yourProjectName’ do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for yourProjectName

pod 'SwiftyJSON’
pod 'Firebase/Core'

end
```