# how to add custom icons using fontAwesome to UIbutton in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, font-awesome, uifont

I am currently working on an IOS application and i want to add button labels or icon using FontAwesome i have successfully installed cocoapods in my project and now i have no idea of using cocoapods for adding library FontAwesome(More info:-[enter link description here](https://github.com/thii/FontAwesome.swift)) icons in my IOS Application.

- I need to know about the procedure of adding FontAwesome using
  cocoapods, 
  and
- I need to know  if their is another way to add FontAwesome to my project

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like below:-

Step1 : Add framework like below image
[image]

Step 2:Drag and drop all .otf and .swift files into your project
Step 3:import FontAwesome_swift
Step 4: Use below code:-

```
let imageView  = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 80.0, y: 80.0, width: 50, height: 50))
imageView.image = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .github, style: .brands, textColor: .black, size: CGSize(width:40,height:40))
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Result:-

[image]

Comment: Hi, Firstly i want to thank you for answering my question. And Secondly i want to thank you again because i followed your instructions and got my desire result.

Comment: @hussnainahmad you are welcome and you feel free to upvote :D Happy coding.

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways of using font awesome icons in an iOS application. 
You can opt out any one of them according to your understanding and comfort.

## Approach 1:

**Writing your own logic**

- Add font awesome files into your compile source and make sure added properly (See the attached pictures)
- Keep Unicode string of any font-awesome icon(In the example code I am taking the close icon reference. Its font awesome class and Unicode texts are `fa-close` and `f00d` respectively (**See example code**). In my case, I have a class where I have all font awesome icon string and another class which accept font awesome class string and returns the appropriate Unicode string.
- Create an attributed string with that Unicode string and set it to attributedText property (**See the example code below**).

You can search your desired font awesome string and Unicode [here](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet)

[image: Your font awesome file looks like something similar to this]

[image: Make sure these font awesome file added to your build-phase source]

## Code Example

**Step1**

In this example, I have created an extension which returns the Unicode string.

```
 extension String {

     func fontAwesomeString(name: String) -> String {

         switch name {
         case "fa-close":
            return "\u{f00d}"
         default: // manage exhaustive case accordingly
         }
      } 
 }
```

**Step2**

Call above method by passing the appropriate font awesome string.

```
let iconUnicodeText = String.fontAwesomeString(name: "fa-close")
let iconAttributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: iconUnicodeText)
self.iConLabel.attributedText = iconAttributed // iConLabel is a control type of UIlabel.
```

Or if you don't want to organise your source code you can directly create an attributed string with Unicode and set to attributedText property.

**Note:** You might be required to make changes in above code snippet. As I have written for Swift 4.0

## Approach 2:

**Using cocoa pods**

Once you installed the pod library, you call the appropriate methods shown in the example as below

```
yourButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 30, style: .brands) 
yourButton.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIcon(name:. gitgub), for : .normal) // you may change icon type with your desired one
```

Comment: IN Approach1 the part about setting the font is missing I used this: `guard let font = NSFont(name: "Font Awesome 5 Free Solid", size: 18) else { fatalError("⚠️️") }` and then set the `textField.font = font`

Answer (score 3):

If you have not already installed CocoaPods, these are good instructions:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25257238/8534588

#### Install FontAwesome with CocoaPods:

1. Open up Podfile which is in the same folder as your .xcodeproj file
2. Add this line to Podfile to install FontAwesome.swift:  `pod 'FontAwesome.swift'`
3. Save changes to Podfile
4. Open up Terminal in the folder that contains Podfile and run the command `pod install`

#### How to use FontAwesome icons:

Add `import FontAwesome_swift` in your code file

Example code:

`let image = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .checkCircle, style: .solid, textColor: UIColor.black, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))`

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in Objective C, So hope this would be useful. The procedure will be same but you need to convert the Objective C code to Swift.

So for do this in Objective C, 
You can follow the step mentioned in this link to add the `FontAwesome` manually to your project without using `CocoaPod`, If you are interested not to use `CocoaPod`

[Manually Add FontAwesome](https://github.com/daltoniam/FontAwesome-iOS)

From that Github project takeout the `NSString` category class, i.e `NSString+FontAwesome`

You need to add the **fontawesome-webfont.ttf** in resource folder as well

**NB:** For me error was coming after I add NSString Category class mentioned there in the above link, If you are facing the issue like duplicate definition then just rename those enum constants those are not satisfying the variable naming convention. (For me some of the enum constant were using hypen(-) i replaced those with underscore(_)).