# I downloaded an open source project that uses CocoaPods. Do I have to install CocoaPods?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

Simple question; title says it all

I downloaded an open source demonstration project. The documentation says it uses CocoaPods.

None of the targets will build (*no such module "Canvas"*—`Canvas` is the framework class I want to review). Searching, the most common solution recommended is "just run pods install again".

Does this mean I have to install CocoaPods to build a project that uses CocoaPods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have never installed CocoaPods on this machine before, get it installed, this post will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/43292864/1244597

Then whenever you download a project that uses pod dependencies, open terminal and type these 2 commands:

```
$ cd PATH_TO_PROJECT
$ pod install
```

**UPDATE** I downloaded the Canvas open source project, you **do not** need to install CocoaPods for this project because the pod library is already available within the project directory, you just run the **Example** project by double clicking this file:

```
/Canvas/Example/Canvas.xcworkspace
```

Comment: Tried that, no joy: Installed CocoaPods using the instructions on their website. cd'd to the example project directory (the one with the PodFile). Ran `pod install`. Got error: __[!] No podspec found for Canvas in ../__, which is clearly wrong because there is a `Canvas+.podspec` file in the parent directory.

Comment: *sigh* This is what bothers me about all of these tools that claim to make development so much simpler; they often just end up making it harder. :(

Comment: Making those edits didn't help. Now I get the error __[!] Unable to find a target named `Canvas`, did find `Canvas_Example` and `Canvas_Tests`.__. Note that the file I had was radically different. Are we talking about the same [Canvas](https://github.com/Authman2/Canvas) project?

Comment: No, I used a different Canvas project, please see my edited update

Comment: Thanks! That worked. (I guess I have to read up on what an Xcode *workspace* is.) Going forward, if I want to use this framework in my project is using CocoaPods the best solution or can I just lift the framework from this GIT project?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will give it a try ... since I already have it installed ;)