# Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics' pod Error on PhoneGap

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, cocoapods, phonegap

I'm developing a hybrid app which is connected to Firebase Analytics.

**The enviroment:**
Windows 10
Visual Studio 2015
DevExtreme Library
PhoneGap cli version 8.0.0
Cordova iOS version 5.0.0
Plugin added: `phonegap-plugin-push`, `cordova-support-google-services` and `cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics`.

**Steps:**

- Build a PhoneGap Zip.
- Upload the code on PhoneGap account.
- Build the app.

**The problem:**
The error is related to pod:

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics" at "1.0.1" for ios
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics': Error: pod: Command 
failed with exit code 1
```

**config.xml**
The following is the last version of the `config.xml`:

```
<widget id="com.devexpress.apptemplate" version="1.0" versionCode="1">
  <name>ApplicationTemplate</name>
  <description>Template</description>
  <author email="email@sample.com" href="http://sample.com">Author</author>
  <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
  <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="60000" />
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-8.0.0" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26" />
  <preference name="cordova-ios" version="5.0.0" />
  <preference name="cordova-android" version="7.1.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" onload="true" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ios-longpress-fix" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" onload="true" />
  <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="2.1.2" />

  <platform name="android">
    <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <framework src="Firebase/Core" type="podspec" spec="~> 5.6"/>
    <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
  </platform>

  <plugin name ="cordova-support-google-services" />
  <plugin name ="cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics" />

  <plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" spec="^2.0.0">
    <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="+" />
  </plugin>
  <plugin name="cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release" spec="^2.0.0">
    <variable name="FIREBASE_VERSION" value="+" />
  </plugin>
  <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you in advanced,
Sara

Comment: Do you have the cocoapods installed? This post maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-to-install-cocoapods

Comment: No, or I don't believe so when I'm building. I'm in Windows, so I don't know how to install them. Plus the build is done online by PhoneGap.