# How to install any modules using cocoa pods for my watchOS

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, watchkit

I need to use alamofire to call the backend and provide the heart rate , but in my ios app view controller its working , but in my app its showing Alamofire not found. How to install alamofire in the watch OS app?

My current podfile is

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'watchPhoneApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for watchPhoneApp
  pod 'MaterialComponents/Cards'
  pod 'Charts'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-rc.2'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'

  target 'watchPhoneAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

And do find my project structure in the screen shot : 
[image: project structure]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install cocoapods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-to-install-cocoapods)

Comment: like i have installed alamofire using cocoapods for my ios app, but how to do it in . watchOS app?

Comment: It's same way you install pod in any app.

Comment: @dahiya_boy please check the above podfile

Comment: how to install for my watchos app

Comment: Try after removing pod version.

Comment: you are saying that i dont have to install alamofire explicitly for 2 different targets? but once will do? ? please check the above folder structure

Comment: What to check in folder structure. I am uncleared with your point.

Comment: okay , just im saying how to install alamofire for my watchos app,

Comment: @dahiya_boy do you know how to acheive that? coz alamofire is not a recognized module in my watch app