# How can I install CocoaPods?

Tags: cocoapods

I tried to install CocoaPods in my terminal. However, it is not working, and I am unable to type my password in. Once I have typed the first line, I can no longer type anything in my terminal, and I can only press <kbd>Return</kbd>, but when I press <kbd>Return</kbd> it misinterprets it as being my password attempt, and finally I can only type once again in my terminal once I pressed <kbd>Return</kbd> three times and failed all the password attempt.

I can't enter my password to install CocoaPods, and I tried pressing on the key icon too. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you aware that the terminal won't show you typing your passwords? It does that so if anyone is watching over your shoulder then they won't be able to see the number of characters your password has...

Comment: Yes I am aware of that but even when I type it in and nothing appears, and I press return, nothing happens.

Comment: Related: *[How do I install CocoaPods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/)*