# React Native IOS platform 'folly/Portability.h' file not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native, react-native-ios

I looked at previously opened topics, no solution,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25257238/12702367

I followed the instructions. I get an error when I start from xcode

'folly/Portability.h' file not found

xcode returns this error

There is no file called folly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMAPt.png)

```
{
  "name": "..",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "buffer": "^5.4.3",
    "formik": "^1.5.2",
    "mobx": "^5.9.4",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
    "react-native-24h-timepicker": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.15",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.27.2",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps.git#c102c36d895cbef8b6a8deefd4c58fb0dc17638e",
    "react-native-uuid": "^1.4.9",
    "react-native-permissions": "2.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.6.1",
    "recyclerlistview": "^2.0.12",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.6.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.6.2",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "resources/fonts"
    ]
  }
}
```

The current podfile.
Could the source of the error be because the folly folder is not transferred correctly?

```
    # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target '..' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ..

# Pods for ..
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'


# Third party deps podspec link
pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'



  target '..Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

That means you haven't properly installed pods! The error says that the Xcode is unable to find the .h file because it is unable to see such libraries or path in project! Try to clean the code first then switch to the terminal and install pod again! I hope it might solve your issue!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
cd ios
pod deintegrate
rm Podfile.lock
pod install
```