# Error in installing pods with pod install

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

got an error in installing pods while doing pod install. I have tried cleaning, deintegrating and reinstalling pods.
i also cleaned the project many times but got no positive results.

```
[!] The plist file at path `path` doesn't exist.
```

[image]

Comment: Try with `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` then try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-to-install-cocoapods. I hope it will work's for you.

Comment: How did you manage to solve it?

Comment: change the info-plist file-path in project settings @Jamil

Answer (score 0):

in most of the case it happen because there is some problem in cocoapod library or cocoapod library is not installed so try below code in terminal and install cocoapod

may it will work

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have moved to the correct folder where the pod file is located