# I am using Mac os 10.14 Mojave, I could not install any pod file in my project

Tags: swift

When I try to run the command "pod init"  it gives me error command not found. After that I try to run the command "sudo gem install cocoapods" then it again gives me error "Failed to build gem native extension" with this message

> current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/ext/ffi_c
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20200701-1901-10omoap.rb extconf.rb
> mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1 for inspection.
> Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.13.1/gem_make.out.

I could not understand the problem.

My Xcode version is 11.3.

Comment: Duplicate  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-to-install-cocoapods

Comment: I try this also but after running the command "sudo gem install cocoapods" it gives me other type of error which is not  mention in this link.

Comment: What is 'this'?

Comment: I remember having installed an older version.

Comment: When I run the command "sudo gem install cocoapods" it gives this error 
Error installing cocoapods:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.13.1/gem_make.out

Comment: If run the command "sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6" it gives no error but after that if I run the command "pod setup" it again gives the error command not found

Comment: In my opinion, the reference to `Library/Ruby` is a bad smell. The first thing to do is get out of the system's Ruby completely and install your own, e.g. with `rbenv`. Now you'll be in control of what gems there are, and you'll never have to say `sudo` again.