# Implement MarqueeLabel in iOS Project Using Xcode/ Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am building an iOS app with Xcode.
In that app is a SpringLabel, with displays a text variable.
I would like the text to scroll when the text string is too long to display across the whole screen.
I found out I could use MarqueeLabel with can be downloaded from GitHub, but I have no idea on how to implement it into my project. I don't know much about programming.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you've tried to solve this problem.

Comment: I have read the instructions. I added the MarqueeLabel package to my project, I added the QuartzCore framework to my project (Targets > MyApp > General > Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content), imported the MarqueeLabel into my project (import MarqueeLabel) and set my SpringLabel class as a MarqueeLabel instead. Got an error saying «Make sure your built products contains either an application or framework product.» Thanks!

Comment: There may be a solution for you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25257238/9743716

Comment: Hello, I've had a look at the instructions, and there seems to be a way to use MarqueeLabel without Cocoapods... «Manual Installation:

1. Add MarqueeLabel.swift, to your project. –
2. Add **QuartzCore.framework** to your project frameworks. –
3. Import MarqueeLabel and replace your UILabels with MarqueeLabels as needed.»