# Tried command 'pod install', this happened

Tags: ruby, xcode, flutter, terminal, cocoapods

I tried running pod install and this is what I received.

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.

zsh: abort      pod install
(base) tazar@Tazs-Air ios % [NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.
```

. What am I doing wrong? Id really appreciate the help.

Comment: try this : brew install cocoapods

Comment: can you write what you have tried also you can look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-do-i-install-cocoapods