# cocopods-genrate plugin not found

Tags: ruby, macos, kotlin, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

System
OS    : macOS (12.6.1)
CPU   : Intel (R) Core - i5
JAVA  : OpenJdk 19
Xcode : 14.1
ruby  : 2.7
gems  : 3.3.11

Im trying to set up the environment for Kotlin Multiplatform for iOS and Android i installed kdoctor, Xcode, Android Studio,OpenJdk and ruby2.7.
Everything is working according to plan but i'am not able to install cocoapods and cocoapods-genrate i tried official documentation of cocoapods https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation and used this command. but kdoctor is not ditectiong cocoapods,
`sudo gem install cocoapods`
i also tried brew method by this command
`brew install cocoapods`
now cocoapods is detected but cocoapods-genrate plugin is not detected. and showed this message
"* cocopods-genrate plugin not found
Get cocopods-genrate from [https://github.com/square/cocoapods-generate#installation"](https://github.com/square/cocoapods-generate#installation%22)
i tred this command but nothing happend.
`gem install cocoapods-generate`

**how to properly install cocopods and cocopods-genrate to set up the environment for Kotlin Multiplatform for iOS and Android?**

Answer (score 0):

1. I used this command to install cocoapods

   `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`
2. Then this command to install cocoapods-generate

   `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods-generate`
3. and finaly `pod setup --verbose` to setup the cocoapods.

I followed this answer and now cocoapods and cocoapods-generate is ditected by kdoctor.

[How do I install CocoaPods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-do-i-install-cocoapods)